# generating xtext artifacts errors

Tags: eclipse, xtext, ecore

I am trying to create a new DSL grammar, so I have developed an ecore model and imported to the xtext grammar file, the xtext file has generated and without errors. later on I have faced mainly 3 errors:

1. a noisy pop up error "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException"
2. when I try to generate the xtext artifacts, it was terminated after a lot of errors, and the errors in below

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
0 [main] INFO lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup - Registering platform uri 'C:\Users\MAISA\Desktop\eclipse-epsilon-1.2-win32-x86_64\workspace'
141 [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher - Problems instantiating module org.xtext.example.mydsl.WSNDSL: 

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems instantiating module org.xtext.example.mydsl.WSNDSL: 

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:95)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.SettingProviderImpl$1$1.setValue(SettingProviderImpl.java:56)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.internalApplyAssignments

(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:143)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.inCase(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.xtext.util.PolymorphicDispatcher.invoke(PolymorphicDispatcher.java:296)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.internalSwitch(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:66)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.internalApplyAssignments

(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:142)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.inCase(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.xtext.util.PolymorphicDispatcher.invoke(PolymorphicDispatcher.java:296)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.internalSwitch(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:66)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.inCase(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.xtext.util.PolymorphicDispatcher.invoke(PolymorphicDispatcher.java:296)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.internalSwitch(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:66)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.Mwe2ExecutionEngine.create(Mwe2ExecutionEngine.java:62)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:93)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.factory.SettingProviderImpl$1$1.setValue(SettingProviderImpl.java:54)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.ConfigurationException: Couldn't find an interface metamodel.MetamodelPackage
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup.addRegisterGeneratedEPackage(StandaloneSetup.java:430)
... 34 more
```

am new to xtext and eclipse, and appreciate any help to solve my errors.

Thanks 
AYMEN

Comment: can you share grammar and workflow as well

Comment: I have added my xtext grammar to the original question body

Answer (score 0):

can you check your workflow. You need to have the `scanClassPath = true`
 and to `register your meta-model`. See the following example :

```
Workflow {
    bean = StandaloneSetup {
        scanClassPath = true
        platformUri = "${runtimeProject}/.."
    }

    .... 
    ....

   component = Generator {
         ....
        language = auto-inject {
            loadedResource = "platform:/resource/org.eclipse.emf.ecore/model/Ecore.genmodel"
         ....
         }
   }
```